# Executing a function to each item on a Nodelist in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an `<img>` to every `<td>` tag with a certain CSS Class in my page.
I used "querySelectorAll" to look them up, like this:

```
var painted = document.querySelectorAll('.painted');
```

Now I would like to add to each one of them a specific image with a unique ID. I assume I need to loop through the list somehow and edit each element's innerHTML, could anyone provide the syntax for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it like a normal `for` loop, and add properties to each element.

```
for (var i = 0, len = painted.length; i < len; i++) {
    painted[i].id = "foo" + i;
    painted[i].innerHTML = "<strong>Your content</strong>";
}
```

This uses `innerHTML` to create new content. If you need more complex content processing then there's no single syntax. You need to learn the DOM API and perform the needed manipulations.

For example, if you wanted to add an image, you can create one and append it directly.

```
for (var i = 0, len = painted.length; i < len; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.id = "myimage" + i;
    painted[i].appendChild(img);
}
```

Notice that I'm not using HTML markup. A DOM node doesn't have "HTML content". It is part of an object tree structure, so it has child nodes, which have their own child nodes, and so on.

So what you need to do, is perform some DOM selection with the current `painted` element as the root, and decide what should go where.

Comment: iv'e used innerHTML like so:
for (var i = 0, len = painted.length; i < len; i++) {
 a = i+1
    painted[i].innerHTML = '<img id="BP'+a+'" src="blackP.png" />';}
How is it different from creating a DOM child?

Comment: and how would I position my new img inside the <td>?

Comment: @Tomcatom: If there is content in the `painted` elements, then it will be destroyed and replaced with the `img`. If there's no content, then it doesn't make too much difference. I prefer to avoid `innerHTML`, because you build the string, and the browser needs to take it apart and turn it into the `img` node. Makes more sense to me to just create the node directly.

Comment: @Tomcatom: I don't know what you mean by "position". Do you mean CSS positioning? Or are there other elements, and you need to put it in the right place relative to those elements?

Comment: I ment how would the HTML string know to put itself between the correct tags, but that was before I saw your latest answer.
Now I would like to set some HTML attributes to the img, how would I do that?
Thanks a million!

Comment: @Tomcatom: One thing you need to realize, is that HTML is what you write on the server side. When it arrives at the client, the browser turns the HTML into the Object structure, so we're really not dealing with tags anymore. If you want to define the `src` of the `img` element you created, just assign the `.src` property. `img.src = "http://example.com/myimage.jpg"` This will give the `img` node the source of the image, just like it would have if you sent HTML markup from the server.

Comment: so basically if I were to change the ID of the element to later use with CSS, I could use the `.id` property?

Comment: @Tomcatom: Absolutely. If the id `#foo` has a certain style, and if you give some element that id using `elem.id = "Foo"`, then the element will receive the style defined in CSS *(of course, keeping in mind that IDs must be unique)*. But the same goes for classes or anything else that can be defined in CSS. The CSS will apply no matter how or when the elements were created and inserted.

Comment: So where does the "setAttribute" function come in?

Comment: @Tomcatom: Well, that's a little strange. Most of the time when you're in JavaScript, you'll want to deal directly with properties. For some properties/attributes, there is an automatic correlation, so for example, you could also use `.setAttribute("id", "foo")`, and the `.id` property will update. This isn't always the case. But generally attributes are what you include in your HTML. And when you do things like clone a node using `.cloneNode`, attributes will also be cloned, but properties will generally not *(but again, some props are automatically tied to attrs, so some will be cloned)*

Comment: OK, so bottom line is I should use properties rather than attributes.
Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Tomcatom: Generally, yes. Most of what you'll need will involve simple manipulations of properties on the objects. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Hi, Iv'e one more question:
Say I wanna add a new property to the "img" element iv'e just created and name it "pstn". How would I do that?

Comment: @Tomcatom: In many ways, a DOM element is an object very much like any other JavaScript object *(ignoring some technicalities)*. So you can go ahead and add a property just like any other object. `img.pstn = "your value"` Some people call these "expando" properties. As long as you're storing basic, primitive data, there should be no problem. I'd be cautious about storing large amounts of data nested in object structures, or references to other DOM elements.

Comment: Iv'e tried `squareID = painted[i].id; img.pstn = squareID;` but when I check the console for any of the img's ID I get back "undefined".

Comment: @Tomcatom: How are you checking?

Comment: BP1.pstn (BP1 is an example of one of the img's name. when I check for other properties the same way it works. for example BP1.src gives me the source etc...)

Comment: @Tomcatom: There's some other issue then. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w4YLU/

Comment: It was indeed some other issue. Fixed it, again, thanks to you :)